# Electron transitions and spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals

Take a single proton and electron. Write $n,\ell,m$ for the quantum numbers of the electron, and $1/2$ or $-1/2$ for its spin.

The space of states of this system is the separable Hilbert space $V$ with orthonormal basis
$$\{v_{n,\ell,m,\pm 1/2}\ : \ n,\ell,m \text{ as above}\}.$$
The Hamtiltonian $H$ is a Hermitian operator on $V$.

*Question:* I'm interested in the probability of one state turning into another, or equivalently in
$$\langle v_{n,\ell,m,\pm 1/2}|H|v_{n',\ell',m',\pm' 1/2}\rangle.$$
What is this, as a function of $n,n',\ell,\ell',m,m',\pm, \pm'$?

---

I'm happy for the answer to be an integral, a sum etc. as long as it's a function of those variables. Since the state is completely described  by $n,\ell,m,\pm 1/2$, no other variables (like $\textbf{S},\textbf{L},\psi,...$) should appear, unless they are some clearly-stated functions of $n,\ell,m,\pm 1/2$.

---

*Edit:* to be clear, $n,\ell,m$ are the principal, azithumal and magnetic quantum numbers.

Secondly, my question is what the real-life entries of $H$ are (because up to a little ambiguity they can be observed). i.e. what are leading few terms after the diagonal, and what physical effects are they caused by?

For instance, some effects which might add non-diagonal terms to $H$: $n$ changing due to absorption/emission of a photon, the spin may effect the energy a bit (causing an "$n$-$\pm 1/2$" off-diagonal term), some "$\ell$-$\pm 1/2$" off-diagonal terms due to the $\mathbf{L}\cdot\mathbf{S}$ terms I've seen before in similar contexts, etc.

Comment: Do you mean the probability of measuring the system to be in one state given that it starts in another? The QM states themselves evolve deterministically, so if you are talking about the evolution of the state function then you shouldn't be talking about probabilities. Can you clarify?

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes, I mean that. I was under the impression that (the square of) $\langle \psi | \exp(iHt/\hbar)| \varphi\rangle$ was the probability that, starting at $\varphi$, it is observed in state $\psi$ when the observation is made at time $t$.

Comment: @AaronStevens In any case, even if I've misunderstood something, the thing I'd like to know are the entries of $H$.

Comment: What physics are you considering in your Hamiltonian? Just the gross structure? Fine structure? Hyperfine structure?

Comment: You can calculate the transition matrix elements. Electric dipole transitions are easiest, lead to selection rules, "forbidding" most transitions.

Comment: @bysymmetry See the edit: I understand that my question is equivalent to choosing the model. That is, the point of the question was to find a model that for instance gives a first-order correction to "$H\approx$ the diagonal with values $E_n$".

Comment: Reference for this question is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule#Summary_table and lecture notes referenced there.

Comment: @BruceGreetham Thanks, this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. Now I know which entries are zero. However, I looked at the lecture notes, and I don't think either mentions how to calculate what the values $H$ has in the entries which selection rules allow to be nonzero. (It does for a couple, but some are given in terms of things like $\textbf{B}$, not $n,\ell,m,\pm 1/2$).

Comment: Search for "Spontaneous emission rate for hydrogen" came up with this http://physicspages.com/pdf/Griffiths%20QM/Griffiths%20Problems%2009.22.pdf

Comment: Search SE for "electric dipole transition" came up with https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284231/is-there-a-list-of-hydrogenic-transition-matrix-elements-online

Comment: The best SE answer I have found for the background theory of the 3 processes (absorption , stimulated emission and spontaneous emission) is https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/314469/transitions-in-qm. The point is, as I understand it, they all boil down to roughly the same matrix element calculations of the type specified in OP question.

Comment: @BruceGreetham Thank you for all of this. If you're interested in points, I'd be happy to give you the bounty if you transcribe that onto an answer.

Comment: Thanks but these comments were just my learning process. In the end I have bought The Quantum Theory of Light (Loudon) - once I've read that I may write up a full answer how all the threads hang together.

Comment: @BruceGreetham I asked someone in person about this. They didn't know the answer, but recommended that (1) the Hilbert space to deal with is $H_\text{electron}\otimes H_\text{light}$ (the first being the one in my question and the second describing the possible states of light) (this then satisfies Accidental's complaint), and (2) that ``An Introduction to Quantum Optics'' by Aspect might actually contain the values of this Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would that this function is determined by what $H$ is, and $\langle v_{n,\ell,m,\pm 1/2}|H|v_{n',\ell',m',\pm' 1/2}\rangle$ is the so-call "matrix-element of $H$ in angular momentum basis".

If we need a general answer, we must look at the symmetry of H. 
Because the $|n,l,m,s\rangle$ is eigenstates of operator $\mathbf{L}^2$, $L_z$, $S^2$, $S_z$, $V(\mathbf{r})$. That means if $H$ commutes with all of these operators, there wouldn't be any off-diagonal elements. Real life example is the ideal Hydrogen atom without relativity.

If there is terms like $L\cdot S$(spin-orbit coupling of atoms) or $\hat{x}$(atom interaction with plane wave lights) in the Hamiltonian. Then $|n,l,m,s\rangle$ is no longer an eigenstate, since $[H,L_z]\ne 0$. These terms will produce off-diagonal elements and it lets 'neighboring' levels couple to each other. In particular, $L\cdot S$ is caused by the fact that a moving electron can 'feel' magnetic field due to relativity.

For a minimum example, let's write things explicitly in (x,y,z) basis for a spinless Hydrogen wave function, and calculate the first few matrix elements.

The wavefunction of hydrogen atom is
$${\displaystyle \psi _{n\ell m}(r,\vartheta ,\varphi )={\sqrt {{\left({\frac {2}{na_{0}^{*}}}\right)}^{3}{\frac {(n-\ell -1)!}{2n(n+\ell )!}}}}e^{-\rho /2}\rho ^{\ell }L_{n-\ell -1}^{2\ell +1}(\rho )Y_{\ell }^{m}(\vartheta ,\varphi )}$$
according to [wikipedia: Hydrogen atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom)

Put the formula in Mathematica

```
a0 = 0.1;
\[Psi][n_, l_, m_, x_, y_, z_] := 
   Sqrt[4 (n - l - 1)!/(a0^3 *n^3 (n + l)!)]
   E^(-2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]/(n a0)/2) 2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]/(n a0)^l  
  LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1,2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]/(n a0)] 
  (-1)^m SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ArcTan[x, y]]
```

Where $a0$ is an arbitrary Bohr radius that I defined.

Visualization:

```
plist = Flatten[Table[{n, l, m}, {n, 2}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, -l, l}], 2];
 Table[
  DensityPlot[
  Evaluate[Abs[\[Psi] @@ (i~Join~{x, 0, z})]]^2, {x, -20. a0, 
  20 a0}, {z, -20 a0, 20 a0}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}],
 {i, plist}]
```

Which gives [image]

Now let $H_I$ be the light matter interaction term. One of the simplest Hamiltonian is
$$ H_I = \hat{V}(x,y,z) = c \hat{x}, $$
where $c$ is a constant and $\hat{x}$ is the $x$ position operator.

For $H_I=x$ the integral is easy without computer, but for a generic $H_I$ you can always calculate it numerically.

```
data = Table[
NIntegrate[
 Conjugate[\[Psi] @@ (i~Join~{x, y, z})] x (\[Psi] @@ (j~
      Join~{x, y, z})),
 {x, -20 a0, 20 a0}, {y, -20 a0, 20 a0}, {z, -20 a0,  a0}],
{i, plist}, {j, plist}]; // Quiet
```

It yields the matrix element of the $nlm=100,200,21-1,210,211$

```
Round[data, 0.0001]
(* {{0., 0., -0.0436, 0., 0.0436}, 
    {0., 0., 0.1882, 0., -0.1882}, 
    {-0.0436, 0.1882, 0., 0., 0.}, 
    {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, 
    {0.0436, -0.1882, 0., 0., 0.}} *)
```

The only non-zero elements are $\Delta l=\pm 1, \Delta m = \pm 1$. For $H_I= \hat{z}$, it is $\Delta m =0$. Combine together, it gives the selection rule $\Delta l=\pm 1, \Delta m = 0,\pm 1$ for electric dipole transition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've already seen things like this, and am only looking for what actual numbers the entries of matrix $H$ are. I can't pretend I understand it properly if I only know how to get the answer in extremely vague terms.

Comment: Can you specify a Hamiltonian as an example? Maybe it's much easy to show if you give a $H$ in operator form, and then the matrix element can be computed.

Comment: One point of the question is that I don't know what the Hamiltonian actually is.

Comment: In this case,  the Hamiltonian in the above example is one of the most basic ones.

Comment: Thanks again, but I doubt this model (i.e. $H_1$) accurately models what actually happens.

Comment: That's true it is not a complete picture. We can add something to it to make it physical. For example, $H_I = \sum_k −e\hat{x}|E0|cos(ω_k t), $ where k are all the allowed wave vector in a box. With this Hamiltonian, you can know the transition probability of a atom under the influence of oscillating E field (light). And evaluating $\langle | x |\rangle$ is one of the difficult step.  other terms only contribute a constant in front of it.